# Saying Hashem's name when studying

Tags: halacha, tanach, torah-study, shemos-sacred-names

I learned somewhere that when you are learning, if you are going to read an entire pasuk without interruption you can say Hashem's name, however if you are going to only say part of the pasuk (for example you will interrupt to read Rashi) you should not say Hashem's name.
Does anyone have any idea where this came from?

Comment: I once saw a pamphlet (from someone out of Lakewood) that discussed the allowance for saying the partial pesukim of "v'zos hatorah..."  and on Shabbos during yotzer or "Tov lehodos laShem".  (Didn't read it so I couldn't even begin to answer your question.)

Comment: @YDK V'zos hatorah is a complete pasuk.

Comment: @DoubleAA, and doesn't have Hashem's name.  I meant the end- "al pi Hashem b'yad Moshe.

Comment: You can always says God's name as part of learning, there is no issue of "shem shemayim levatalah" when its part of torah. however many ashkenazim refrain from saying it when not reciting the whole passuk.

Comment: @ArielK sources?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Yalkut Yosef vol. 3 pg 548-549:*

> הלומד בש''ס ובמדרשי חז''ל, ופוגע בפסוקים שיש בהם אזכרות שם שמים, יש לו לקראם כקריאתן בתנ''ך בהזכרת שם שמים, ואין להחמיר בזה ולכנות ולבטאת ''אלוקים'' בקו''ף ולא בה''א, או לומר ''אדושם'', או ''המוני'', שהואיל ומדינא שרי, המחמיר יוצא שכרו בהפסדו, דהוי כמכנה שם כלפי מעלה. אולם אזכרות שבמטבע ברכות המובאים בש''ס ובמדרשי חז''ל ובפוסקים, אין לקראם כי אם בכינוי ''השם''. וכמו כן יכנה לומר אלוקים, או אלוקינו בקו''ף.
>
> והוא הדין בזה למי שדורש ברבים, ומזכיר בדרשתו איזה פסוק, שרשאי לומר שם ה' כקריאתו, ולא יכנה לומר ''השם'' וכיו''ב. ואפילו אם אינו אומר פסוק שלם, אלא חלקו בלבד, רשאי להזכיר שם ה' או אלוקים בה''א.
>
> מותר לברך ולהזכיר שם ה' לשם לימוד לקטן, עד שיהיה רגיל בברכות. וצריך לחנך את הקטנים לברך ברכות המצות וברכות הנהנין, הן ברכה ראשונה והן ברכה אחרונה. וקטן שעדיין לא יודע לברך, מותר לחנכו לברך כמה פעמים על כל פרי ופרי, אף שדעתו היה לאכול יותר מפרי אחד. וכשהאב מחנך את בנו או בתו לברך, מותר לו להזכיר שם ה' בברכה, ואין בזה חשש משום ברכה לבטלה. אבל כשהבן יודע כבר לברך, ורק צריך לעזור לו בברכה, יש להמנע מלומר שם ה'. ומותר לחנך את הקטן לברך אף שאינו יודע לקנח עצמו יפה.
>
> One who is learning Shas and Midrashim and arrives at Pesukim which have Hashem's name, he should say it like he is reading Tanach with Hashem's name *(Shu"t Yaabetz volume 1 Siman 81. Hesed LaAlafim 215:7. Maharsha Berachot 6a)* And there isn't (space) to be strigent to say say Adoshem etc...and those who are stringent his reward gets lost with his loss...However, blessings from Shas and Midrashim etc. should be said 'Hashem' or 'Elokim' *(Birke Yosef 215:4)*...This is also the Halacha for someone giving a Derasha in public and says a Pasuk, he is permitted to say Hashem's name, and he shouldn't say "Hashem." And even if he is not saying a complete Pasuk, rather only a piece, he is permitted to say Hashem's name...It is permitted to bless and say Hashem's name to teach a child until he is regular in reciting Berachot.

*(see also Orhot Sion vol. 3 11:13 for many more sources).*

Comment: "Beli Neder, exact sources I know." ?

Comment: @ArielK I was in a hurry. Random way of phrasing things.

Comment: @HachamGabriel: could you tell me what siman that's in, so that if I look it up in a different edition of Yalkut Yosef with different pagination, I can find it to show somebody?

Comment: @Chanoch Siman 215 (Resh Tet Vav)