# Meditation before Mitzvah activities

Tags: minhag, tefilla, sources-mekorot, mitzvah, prayer-book

Who invented the [meditation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28072/may-one-say-the-letters-of-hashems-name-i-e-yud-hei-vov-hei?noredirect=1#comment66780_28072) that is often printed before such things as counting the 'Omer, inviting the Ushpizin, and other Mitzvoth or Mitzvah-related activities, and what is the basis for it?

Comment: http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%97%D7%95%D7%93#מקורות התפילה והפולמוס סביב אמירתה implies it was designed by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliyahu_de_Vidas

Comment: @double aa, that was impressively fast.

Comment: I checked it earlier before I wrote that no rishonim said it. always pays to double check before one claims something

Comment: @DoubleAA, sounds like an answer....

Comment: I'm not so sure that it should be considered an invention, per se...