# Why is the hey in Elo-* replaced with a kuf?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, aleph-bet-letters

As we know when we write Hashem's name, we replace the hey with a kuf. Why davka a kuf?  For example: Elokai, Elokeinu, Elokah, or "Yud-Key-Vav-Key".  And in "Yud-key-vav-key", why is it pronounced that way instead of "Yud-kuf-vav-kuf"

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28072/may-one-say-the-letters-of-hashems-name-i-e-yud-hei-vov-hei?rq=1#comment66815_28098

Comment: Also shin daled yud is usually replaced as shakay with a kuf.  Tzeva-os is usually pronounced Tzevakos with a kuf.  Kuf seems to be the letter of choice.

Comment: hay and quf look alike. One just has a longer leg.

Comment: Just a thought,Kuf is also the only letter which the throat is blocked when pronouncing it this way you would guarantee not pronouncing a hei which the sound emanates solely from the throat.

Comment: The daled and the hey both can be changed into a kuf easily (and the kuf echoes their shapes as a reminder to the reader). Reading "vav key" highlights the shape of the letter (K) and the sound that one SHOULD be saying (hey).

Answer (score 1):

R' Moshe Bamberger once said the the *kuf* (which means "monkey" in Hebrew) is a mocking imitation of the *hei*, since it looks similar.

[This article](http://mobile.myjewishlearning.com/holidays/Jewish_Holidays/Purim/Themes_and_Theology/context-purim.shtml) takes this concept further, saying that while the *hei* represents the Divine kingship, the *kuf* represents the earthly kingship. However, in this world HaShem's presence is usually hidden behind a mask of the physical world, just as the *hei* is replaced with the *kuf* when pronouncing HaShem's name.