# Hyphenating the word Hashem

Tags: minhag, shemos-sacred-names, english, spelling-variants

I've seen the word Hashem hyphenated (*"Hash-m"*).  Is there any valid reason for this practice?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83/when-blogging-emailing-etc-do-i-use-god-or-g-d?rq=1

Comment: What do you mean validity? Are you asking if the practice is permitted? Do you want to know if it accomplishes something? What? If it avoids something? What?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The names of Hashem which may not be erased are listed in [Shulchan Oruch Yoreh Daioh 276 (9)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40534&st=&pgnum=266&hilite=).

Hashem is not one of them and so the hyphenated ("Hash-m") seems unnecessary.

Comment: The name "Hashem" was not around when the Shulchan Aruch was written so this is not a proof.

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe it is. Maybe the _SA_'s list is all-inclusive, so "God", "Hashem", and the like can be erased. That's what the wording of the _SA_ sounds like to me.

Comment: @msh210 maybe. but you have to show that he meant it to be conclusive. You can't just argue from silence, as this post does.

Comment: @DoubleAA but Hakadosh Baruch Hu was.

Comment: @Shmuel No it wasn't. הקדוש ברוך הוא might have been.

Comment: @DoubleAA all the more so

Comment: @ShmuelBrin All the more so...what?

Comment: So why does "is" and "be" get written? Why not I- or B-? Or is it OK to use his name in any other language besides Hebrew?

Answer (score 2):

Hashem is what we use in place of one of the Aibishter's holy names. It simply means The Name. Perhaps people generalize from the examples of G-d and L-rd, and replace the e with a hyphen.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Jay Marme, and thanks for your suggestion. I hope you look around at our other questions, read [about the site](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/about), and stick around.