# Name of Hashem in vain

Tags: shemos-sacred-names

Which name or names of Hashem may not be said in vain?  The Mishna Berurah in siman 215 #19 says that the issur is not just the four letter name, but applies to Hashem's other names as well. His source the tshuvas Rivash #408 mentions that the mention of malchus in brachos is not a name of Hashem and therefore may be said.  Is the Mishna Berurah only telling us we can't say the seven names which cannot be erased mentioned in Yoreh Deah 276 9? Or is there a different list for this issur.

**Edit** I've since found the Minchas Chinuch in mitzvah 69 #2 saying it is simple to him that this issur only applies to the names which cannot be erased. I would still like to know if there are any halachic sfarim addressing this.

Is there a sourced reason to be stringent regarding the other names?

In particular I'm curious about Hallelujah and why people feel the need to say Halleluka. But I'm making this a more general question.

Comment: +1 very similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23463/759

Comment: @Double that is similar. And yet I didn't find it when I was searching the site before posting.